# Changing timezone in all the servers of a cluster: unexpected side-effects to consider

Tags: ntp, timezone

We want to change the timezone of a cluster of Ubuntu machines from `PT` to `UTC` (so we move a few hours into the future).

The change would be done by changing the servers in the `/etc/ntp.conf` file (because we are using local ntp servers and we want to use public ones instead) and setting `/etc/timezone` appropriately.

Can you help me track what could be the possible impacts of this change (on a live system that will not be rebooted)?

Thinking about cron jobs, postgres databases, mesos, etc.

Comment: why are you deploying a  new set of ntp servers? this seems irrelevant to changing a time zone

Comment: Bad wording, I just meant that we will set new NTP server entries in `/etc/ntpd.con`. I will fix the text